# Ruby on Rails Paper clip old files name issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm using Rails 4 and after added paper clip initializer code  to initialize the user files name by user ID to give every file different name  using this code

**In the initialize file**

```
# initializers images names by the model id (:id)
Paperclip.interpolates :parent_id do |a, s|
    a.instance.contract.id
end
```

**In the model**

```
  has_attached_file :photo ,
                    :url => "/system/files/users/:basename_:id.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/files/users/:basename_:id.:extension"
```

Now it's work well by give the file his basename_fileID.file extension

but I notes that I was missed all the old files links because the new link will search about the file contain the basename and fileID something like that "**image_1.jpeg**" but the old link search about  basename only  something like "**image.jpeg**"

so how I can solve it in Rails without change my old files name on server ??

Is there's some thing in Rails 4 allow me to inform the links  to get the old path in some cases or not ??

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this issue by check if the file exist on server or not by using  `File.exist?`

**The code**

```
<% if File.exist?(@user.photo.path) %>
   <!--The new path -->    
   <%= link_to "Photo", @user.photo.url %>
<% else %>
    <!--The old path -->
    <%= link_to root_url+'system/files/users/'+@user.photo_file_name, :title => "show image" do %>Photo<% end %>
<% end %>
```